# ¿Como mostrar la barra de progreso con `pace.js` y después el contenido de la pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressbar

Estoy utilizando la libreria [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) y lo que quiero hacer es que primero me aparezca la barra y luego el contenido de mi pagina con una animación `.fadein()` de JQuery   y el problema que tengo es que me muestra ambas.

Para ser Honesto no entiendo la librería **pace.js**

**El resultado es el siguiente:**

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[De este sitio descargue la libreria `pace.js`](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/)

Comment: pon algún ejemplo de código que ayas echo...

Comment: Pues de los ejemplos que vi en esa libreria ninguno pone el loadin antes que cargue el html. Siempre se ejecutan ambos.

Comment: Ese es el dilema, realmente no conozco la libreria y busco que primero aparezca la barra, pero al igual todo lo que he visto, se reduce a que se cargan juntos

Answer (score 0):

Te dejare este ejemplo aqui, no esta terminado. Pero tienes una idea. cuando tenga tiempo te ayudo

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
$(function() {
move();
    $(".preload").fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $(".content").fadeIn(1000);        
    });
});
```

```css
.content {display:none;}
.preload { width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;}



#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myProgress" class="preload">
  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
</div>
<div class="content">Hello word</div>
```